# Laravel Setup - "AllowOverride all" is causing a 403

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, webserver, apache2, laravel-5

Trying to get a test Laravel project running on the server. If I navigate to the sites URL I am presented with the Laravel welcome screen but none of the routes are working.

To fix this I have changed the .htaccess file as specified by the laravel website.

The problem is in order for the .htaccess to be utilised I have to "AllowOverride all" in my virtualhost file which is causing a 403 to be presented instead of the welcome page.

The error I'm getting is:

**Forbidden**

**You don't have permission to access / on this server.**

**Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request**

Just for testing purposes I have given the entire laravel folder 777 to make sure there isn't a a file permission issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**Content of my .htaccess:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**Content of my VirtaulHosts:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/testProject1/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory />
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please could you update your question with the contents of your VirtualHost directive? Also, make sure you haven't put `AllowOverride All` in the `.htaccess` file. That should only be in your `VirtualHost` directive.

Comment: Hi Mike, I've added both pieces of information to the original question. Thanks

Comment: Where are the `<VirtualHost>` tags? Or did you just not copy those in?

Comment: Yeh sorry, I have those in there, just didn't past them.

Comment: And what version of Apache are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Directory>` must refer to an absolute path, whereas `<Location>` can refer to a path relative to the document root.

As such, change:

```
<Directory />
```

to:

```
<Directory /var/www/testProject1/public>
```

And don't forget to reboot Apache.

Comment: Hi Mike, if I specify an absolute path I am receiving the same 403 error regardless of whether AllowOverride is set to "None" or "All". Whereas previously it was only with "All". Any ideas?

Comment: It should just be `All`. Please check your error logs - there will be more details in there.

Comment: Hi Mike, had another look through the logs, I think mod_security is stopping everything and giving me a 403. Is there a way to temporarily disable it in order to verify?

Comment: in `httpd.conf`, you should be able to comment out the `LoadModule` directive that loads up `mod_security`, but I have never tried that myself. Could you share the relevant entry from the log?

Comment: Hi Mike, your original suggestion made it work but my mod_security was stopping it working. I'll accept your initial answer as correct. Thanks again!